# Svn caret notation not working on WinXP

Tags: svn

Quote from SVN manual:

> In Subversion 1.6, a new caret (^) notation was introduced as a
>   shorthand for “the URL of the repository's root directory”. For
>   example, you can use the ^/tags/bigsandwich/ to refer to the URL of
>   the /tags/bigsandwich directory in the root of the repository. Note
>   that this URL syntax works only when your current working directory is
>   a working copy—the command-line client knows the repository's root URL
>   by looking at the working copy's metadata. Also note that when you
>   wish to refer precisely to the root directory of the repository, you
>   must do so using ^/ (with the trailing slash character), not merely ^.

But when I run:

```
C:\Svn_Working_Copies\Test1\branches\ver_1_0\Project1>svn log ^/
```

On my WinXP workstation, using svn version 1.7, where Test1 is a working copy of an svn repository I get the following error:

```
svn: E155007: 'C:\' is not a working copy
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The caret is an escape character for your windows command line.  Use a double caret (i.e. `^^`) instead.

Comment: Note that quoting the path also works (e.g. svn log "^/"). I opted for this since I'm writing samples in documentation for Windows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: @JasonKostempski - I find that on Windows 7 quoting -must- be used.